# DNAT iptables rule on rooted Android phone?

Tags: iptables

How i can set `iptables` rule like this on my rooted Android phone:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -s 192.168.1.100 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT -–to-destination 192.168.1.101:8080`

... since Android iptables implementation doesn't support protocol by name and DNAT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577268/iptables-in-android)

1. iptables is available in Android source distribution.
2. **Users of retail Android devices cannot access iptables** binary. **Even Android OS itself cannot access that binary.** This is hard-coded in Android. Many devices also don't have iptables at all.
3. The only way to access iptables binary is to build your own Android images. Check out http://randomizedsort.blogspot.com/2010/08/building-android-and-linux-kernel-for.html. Once you get comfortable with that process, check out http://randomizedsort.blogspot.com/2011/03/porting-iptables-1410-to-android.html.

`iptables` is a default module in [aosp](/questions/tagged/aosp), you can use netfilter to write c code to handle that.

For example, you can create an android project, and write a JNI file, use ndk-build to compile that, and then [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) push the executable to the android file system to execute. And in the mobile end, you can adb shell to it, directly use iptables command as a root user, just like in Linux.

To check if your device supports iptables:

Issue the following command in ADB shell or in Terminal Emulator:

```
iptables -L -t nat
```

Alternatively you could try the beta of  [IP Tables app on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mgranja.iptables&hl=en) to see if it does what you want.

There is also [Droid Wall](https://code.google.com/p/droidwall/wiki/CustomScripts) that you could try. It supports scripts that may help, e.g.

```
$IPTABLES -A "droidwall" --destination "192.168.0.1" -j RETURN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try AFWall+ for example. Available in Play Store and in F-Droid.